# Solving the trigonometric equation $\cos^2x\cos^2(90 - x) = 0.1$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve:

$$\cos^2 x \cos^2 (90-x) = 0.1$$

How do you simplify this equation? I know that $\cos(90-x) = \sin x$ but I don't really know how to make use of that here.

Comment: do you mean $$\cos^2(x)\cos^2(\pi/2-x)=1/10$$?

Comment: Group the two squares: you get an equation $(A)^2=B$, then $A=\pm\sqrt{B}$, etc.

Comment: I think you mean $\cos^2(90^\circ - x)$. The degree symbol is important here, as otherwise it doesn't mean what you probably think it means.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I assume that you are working with degrees and not arclength. First use the complementary angle formula for sine and cosine:

$\cos(90-x) =\sin(x).$

$\cos^2 x\cos^2(90-x)=0.1 \implies \cos^2 x\sin^2(x)=0.1 \implies 2^2\cos^2 x\sin^2(x)=0.4 \implies (2\sin x \cos x)^2=0.4 \implies \sin^2 2x=0.4$

At the end I used the double angle formula for sine $2\sin x \cos x = \sin 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify further:
$$\sin^22x=0.4\iff\frac{1-\cos 4x}2=0.4\iff \cos 4x=0.2,$$
so $\;\;4x\equiv \pm\arccos(0.2)\mod 2\pi$ and eventually
$$x\equiv\pm\frac14\arccos(0.2)\mod \frac\pi2.$$